# How to Determine WHEN a Synced Bookmark in Microsoft EDGE was Created

Tags: office365, microsoft-edge, bookmarks

I am trying to determine the date a bookmark was created in Microsoft EDGE.  The bookmark is a "synced" bookmark.  The reason for determining when the bookmark was made is that the origin/reason for the bookmark is a mystery, but knowing the time it was created will greatly narrow down how/why the bookmark was created.

Comment: Hi @OB7DEV How about the issue? Is [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70535929/how-to-determine-when-a-synced-bookmark-in-microsoft-edge-was-created/70540205#70540205) helpful to deal with the issue? Please let me know if there is anything that I can help here.

Comment: thank you.  I've marked it as the answer.  Indeed it is the answer and I found out when the bookmark was created thanks to your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the Edge bookmarks file to determine the date of a bookmark creation. The file location is `C:\Users\<Username>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Edge\User Data\<Profilename>\Bookmarks`.

You can open the file with **Notepad** and you can find the json data in the file. In the field `date_added`, that's the date of the bookmark creation. That's a long string of numbers, you can convert it to date using the code below:

```
var timeValue = '13285408186887489'; //use your own date value
new Date(Date.UTC(1601,0,1) + timeValue / 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has replaced the old Microsoft Edge with Chromium based Microsoft Edge, so now the history/bookmark file format is same as Google Chrome uses. It is a sqlite db.

Accessing data from this db is fairly easy using sqlite API or any Db explorer utility.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a way to query my Edge bookmarks. Frustrated with jq and jql (written in Rust), I reverted to F# and its JSON type-provider. This script worked for me (you'll have to find FSharp.Data, after installing it with Nuget. I used dir fsharp.data.dll /s/b , from my home directory, to find it.) (Now I wish I'd written it in PowerShell, which would be more generally-usable.)

```
// find all urls whose name contains rust
#r """C:\Users\[myusername]\.nuget\packages\fsharp.data\4.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\FSharp.Data.dll"""
open FSharp.Data
open System
let fn = """C:\Users\[myusername]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Edge\User Data\Default\Bookmarks"""
let bm = JsonValue.Load(fn)
let jdate0 = new DateTime(1601,1,1)
for c in bm.["roots"].["bookmark_bar"].["children"] do
    if c.["name"].ToString().ToLower().Contains("rust") then
        let dta = Double.Parse(c.["date_added"].InnerText())
        let dt = jdate0.AddMilliseconds(0.001*dta).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm")
        printf "%s : %s\n\t%s\n" dt (c.["name"].InnerText()) (c.["url"].InnerText() )
```